# Is Conway's "Course in Functional Analysis" suitable for self-studying?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Is John B. Conway's book "A Course in Functional Analysis" a good book for self-studying functional analysis?

(I have a solid knowledge of undergraduate analysis and linear algebra, group theory, general topology and I am familiar with basic techniques and theorems of complex analysis. I usually prefer generality instead  of unneccesary constrictions and am comfortable with the omission of trivial steps in proofs.)

Comment: It's a great book so it should be doable, but you might also want to supplement it with Kreyszig's book. There are also lots of good functional analysis course notes pdfs from graduate courses floating around online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been a while since I studied it, but I've used this as a course text to a course I couldn't attend the lectures of, and it wasn't exceptionally hard to pass. Your comments give no immediate reason to suspect it would be a bad choice; but be prepared for a quite substantial amount of proofs "left to the reader".

Answer (score 1):

I was going through this book today, and I think it would be way easier to digest the material if one read Kreyszig first (and also had some measure theory knowledge...)